# Creating large arrays in mpir

Tags: c, arrays, memory, large-data

For small arrays and floating number in mpir I get no error messages but when i wanted to create a very large array. say >100,000,000 I get the following error message:

GNU MP: Cannot allocate memory (size=16)
Press any key to continue . . .

Unfortunately I require 2 large arrays. one of size 100,010,000 and another of size 1,000,100. Is this possible on a windows 64bit machine?

Is there a way of clearing part of an array from memory but not the whole of an array(on MPIR) to create space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't allocate that much memory successfully into one array because the elements of an array must appear consecutively in memory, and it's very unlikely that the current state of your heap would allow for something like that.

Assuming you're talking about `float` arrays where a `float` on your system likely has a size of `4`, the only possible way for you to be able to allocate 400MB of memory is if there exists 400 million **consecutive** memory addresses that aren't occupied.

**edit:** I'm not saying it's impossible, I'm only saying that it's unreliable.

**edit 2:** A solution would be for you to allocate memory in chunks. Instead of one array of 100 million floats, you can allocate it in groups of 1 million floats. It's much more likely that you can allocate 100 chunks of 4MB rather than 1 chunk of 400MB.